# how to insert a new LinearLayout after a specific one everytime i click a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to build some sort of twitter application. In DashboardActivity i need to add a status box everytime i click the "Post" button.My dashboard xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
       <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>  -->header layout
       <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>  -->some layout with some titles
        <LinearLayout></LinearLayout> --> post status layout with the post button
       <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>  --> layout with a horizontal rule
       <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>  --> this is the layout with id "rootStatusBox" where i want to add the status box
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, i want to be able to add a new LinearLayout after the horizontal rule layout everytime i click the "Post" button.
I tried something like this in my DashboardActivity:

```
postStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
               addUserStatusBox(firstname,lastname,status);

        }});
```

And addUserStatusBox() looks like this:

```
 public void addUserStatusBox(String firstname, String lastname,String status) {        
    LinearLayout rootStatusBox = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootStatusBox);

    LinearLayout userStatusBox = new LinearLayout(this);
    userStatusBox.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    userStatusBox.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setMargins(0, 300, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    userStatusBox.setLayoutParams(layout);

    TextView friendName = new TextView(this);
    TextView friendStatus = new TextView(this);
    TextView dataCrearePost = new TextView(this);

     friendName.setText(firstname+ " " + lastname);
     friendName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     friendName.setTextSize(10);
     friendName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

     friendStatus.setText(status);
     friendStatus.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     llp.setMargins(-70, 20, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
     friendStatus.setLayoutParams(llp);
     friendStatus.setTextSize(10);

     userStatusBox.addView(friendName);
     userStatusBox.addView(friendStatus);

     rootStatusBox.addView(userStatusBox);
}
```

This is working only for the first time when i add a status.I don't know how to add more posts after the horizontal rule layout and to be able to see the old posts below my new one.I would appreciate a little bit of help.Thank you

Comment: I would highly recommend using a ListView for this instead of manually building each row if at all possible.

Comment: can you give me a basic example of how should i do that in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a customized list view for this purpose.

You need to create the following:

1. **Layout for ListItem:** This represents single row in the list. You can customize it by creating separate **layout** for this. Say you create: **listitem_post.xml**
2. **Adapter:** Write an adapter by extending BaseAdapter class (say: **PostsAdapter.java**). Fill in all the overridden methods. Most importantly, in the getView() method, inflate the post_listitem. Assign that to convertView object (which is passed in as an argument).

   ```
   public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_post, parent, false);
       }
   //Code other parts
   return convertView;
   }
   ```
3. **Activity:** In your xml code of activity, insert a ListView say **listview_posts**. In the java file for the activity, set adapter created in step 2 for listview_posts inside onCreate() method.

   ```
       PostsAdapter postsListAdapter = new PostsAdapter();
       ListView postsListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview_posts);
       postsListView.setAdapter(postsListAdapter);
   ```

That is how you specify that each list element is **listitem_post**.

[**Follow this tutorial**](http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial/)

Comment: Hei again. Do you have any idea how can i store all my list views to SharedPreferences? Cause i need all posts to remain in place after i close the application and come back.

Comment: The easiest way is to save ur business model (the list of posts). You don't need to save list items or the list view, they should be created after loading the objects. I assume u have a class "Post" or sth like that. Make that class implement Serializable interface. If you have properties of that class which are objects which should be saved and retrieved, then make them serializable too.

Comment: //To write:                                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir()
+ File.separator + filename);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(posts);                                              // To read:                                                            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(context.getFilesDir()
+ File.separator + filename);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

posts = (<Cast it!!>) ois.readObject();